# Selendroid wating for an element in native app

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, selendroid

I am using `Selendroid` to test my `android` `application`. Its working fine but I am having a couple of problems. One is that when the app is opened an element is loaded after sometime, for now I am using `Thread.sleep();` as a work around but I want to use built in waiting conditions which are not at all working for me. Please if I can get a answer to that it will be helpful.
currently am implementing the following code

`WebElement referImage = waitForElement(By.id("imageView_close"),30,driver);
 referImage.click();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to my question after some more research
changed the above code to 
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 WebElement element =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
 .id("imageView_close")));
 element.click();`